# Is there a way to avoid defining multiple repeating attributeTemplates of the same type in a Property Grid

Tags: c#, datatemplate, propertygrid

I am using a PropertyGrid and have overridden the standard editbox with a custom NumerictextBox by defining a custom attribute template as seen here:

```
        <attributeTemplates:AccountSetupTemplates.NumericTextBox>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModels:AccountSetupViewModel}">
            <Grid>
                <TextBox DataContext="{StaticResource AccountSetupViewModel}" MaxLength="7" Text ="{Binding         Attributes.Port}">
                    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                        <behaviors:NumericTextBoxBehavior/>
                    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                </TextBox>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </attributeTemplates:AccountSetupTemplates.NumericTextBox>
```

I then substitute the standard editbox from the PropertyGrid with this one. As you can see, this particular NumericTextBox is binded to the Port string.

The problem is that there are several other cases where a NumericTextBox should be used (about five more cases), where in each case, the control will need to be binded to a different string other than Port.

Currently, this means that I must define several such attributeTemplates, which seems silly. Is there a way that I can re-use the same attributeTemplate  multiple times, with each instance binded to a different property string?

Thanks.